# Understanding the difference over output to stdout and a regular file

Tags: bash, sh, io-redirection

This is the output of `ls` command:

```
$ ls
addr.sh  hello.txt  test.sh  xxx.txt
```

Here we have the same command with redirection to **stderr**:

```
$ ls 1>&2
addr.sh  hello.txt  test.sh  xxx.txt
```

Which produces pretty much the same output.

However redirection to a regular file causes `ls` to produce a multi-line output:

```
$ ls > xxx.txt
$ cat xxx.txt
addr.sh
hello.txt
test.sh
xxx.txt
```

Why and what is happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why

Because someone programmed it that way.

> what is happening

Your implementation of `ls` checks if standard output is connected to a terminal device. If it is, it outputs a pretty printed output separated by spaces in a column-like fashion. If the output isn't a terminal device, it outputs a newline separated list.*

Checking if a file decriptor is opened on a terminal can be done with `test -t FD` command that internally calls `isatty()` C function.

`ls` basically works like:

```
{ if [ -t 1 ]; then ls -C; else ls -1; fi }
# From man ls:
# -C     list entries by columns
# -1     list one file per line.
```

Many utilities change their behavior when the output is not a terminal device.

*Note that [POSIX ls specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html) mandates the output to be list of one entry per file when the output is not a terminal `The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard output; the exceptions are to terminals [...]`.

> behind the scenes?

I assume you have coreutils `ls` implementaion. At [coreutils/ls.c#L1886](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L1886) program just checks if `isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)` and depending on that sets quoting style and column-like or newline-like output.

Comment: Quick to answer and very comprehensive! Thank you!